# Pandas Automatic Identification of freq for pd.date_range from data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, date-arithmetic

I am trying to develop a framework to work with Time Series Data. I read the Time Series Data in a pandas dataframe, which contains a Time column. The Time freq may be an Hour / Day / Quarter / Month etc. 
I am currently stuck at creating the future Time Values for the forecasts.

For eg if the series was monthly, I can acheive it using:

`forecast_period = pd.date_range(start='1994-09-01', periods=12, freq='MS')`

But I need a generic way, which is able to find the frequency of a time series automatically and generate future values ( similar to extrapolation).

Comment: `which is able to find the frequency of a time series automatically` - Can you add some sample data? Generally not possible, but it depends

Comment: The obvious thing is to sort the data in increasing datetime, exclude duplicates, take the interval between each sample, then take the mode of that (to exclude outliers, gaps etc.). But you need to post some example data to [prevent this being closed as 'Too Broad'/'Needs Details'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Alternatively, your code can just heuristically try to fit intervals increasing from (say) 1h to 1d to 1month to 3months to 12months, and return the lowest that works.

Comment: I was also thinking, it might not be possible in a simple way. Probably I will have to design a rule based method  heuristic to return the sample frequency given time differences between some initial data points. Anyways thanks for your comments :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to find the freq using a rule based approach. I guess this will work in most situations. Any feedback is welcome.

```
def findSampleFreq(ts, nrows=10, time_col='TimeStamp'):
n = min(nrows, ts.shape[0])

t_diffs = []
for i in np.arange(n):
    td = ts.loc[i+1, time_col]-ts.loc[i, time_col]
    t_diffs.append(td)

avg_diff = np.mean(t_diffs)

diff_ns = avg_diff.value
diff_us = diff_ns / 1000
diff_ms = diff_us / 1000
diff_sec = diff_ms / 1000    
diff_min = diff_sec / 60
diff_hour = diff_min / 60
diff_day = avg_diff.days
diff_wk = diff_day / 7
diff_month = diff_day / 30.4375
diff_qtr = diff_day / 91.3125
diff_yr = diff_day / 365.25

#the unit having minimum absolute difference with 1
# is the sampling freq
diffs = [np.abs(1-diff_ns), np.abs(1-diff_us), np.abs(1-diff_ms),
         np.abs(1-diff_sec), np.abs(1-diff_min), np.abs(1-diff_hour),
         np.abs(1-diff_day), np.abs(1-diff_wk), np.abs(1-diff_month),
         np.abs(1-diff_qtr), np.abs(1-diff_yr)]

aliases = ['N', 'U', 'L', 'S', 'T', 'H', 'D', 'W', 'MS', 'Q', 'YS']    
id = diffs.index(min(diffs))
return aliases[id]
```